# Make a keyboard shortcut to do three finger swipes

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, trackpad, multi-touch

How do I create a keyboard combination that can be held down to treat the successive mouse moves as if they were three-finger-on-trackpad movements?

So I can hold down e.g. cmd and shift, then move the mouse, and it would be as if I were performing that movement with three fingers, to perform things like

- change spaces
- expose mission control
- show application windows

There are of course already individual keyboard shortcuts for all of the three-finger trackpad actions.

However, these are (often) two-handed keyboard shortcuts.

I would like to configure a left-hand only "modifier", which will then treat my next mouse move as if it were performed with three fingers.

Comment: RE: "(which does things like change spaces, expose mission control, and show application windows)" -- There are already _keyboard shortcuts_ for these _actions_.

Comment: @user3439894 they are two-handed keyboard shortcuts, and I want a left-hand only "modifier", which will then treat my next mouse move as if it were performed with three fingers.

Comment: You can change the default shortcuts in [System Preferences] > [Keyboard] > [Shortcuts].

Comment: @JivanPal that doesn't help for this question

Answer (score 1):

I made [Mac Mouse Fix](https://mousefix.org).

It lets you use Mission Control, App Exposé, and Switch between Spaces by simply clicking and dragging in different directions. It also feels super responsive and native.

(I works almost exacly like OP asked for, with the difference that you'll have to hold a Mouse Button - instead of Keyboard Modifiers - and then move the mouse to simulate Trackpad input.)

On top of that it's open source, easy to use, 100% free, and it also has a bunch of other cool features that make your mouse better!

[Download](https://mousefix.org) | [GitHub](https://github.com/noah-nuebling/mac-mouse-fix)

Comment: Great tool, thanks!